# Refactor code for two switch case statement

Tags: ios, swift, switch-statement, refactoring

I'm working on a swift project and have a question to refactor my code.

I'm writing code for checking if a user authorized both the camera and microphone authorization in the app. I wrote the following codes, but I guess (and I hope) I can refactor the code because I think the code below is unclear. I understood basic Swift grammar and gradually understood the compiled language, but let me know if there is a way to make this more readable or easy to write.

What I want to do here is...

- check if both a camera and a microphone are authorized.
- if both of them are authorized, show View Controller with showNextVC().
- if one of nor neither of the item is authorized, show an alert with showConfigurationAlert

  ```
  func checkAuthStatus(){
      checkCameraStatus()
  }

  func checkCameraStatus() {
      switch AVCaptureDevice.authorizationStatus(for: .video) {
      case .notDetermined:
          print("not Determined")
          AVCaptureDevice.requestAccess(for: .video) { granted in
              if granted {
                  print("Now it's granted")
              }
          }
      case .restricted:
          print("restricted")
          showConfigurationAlert(for: "camera")
      case .denied:
          print("denied")
          showConfigurationAlert(for: "camera")
      case .authorized:
          checkMicrophoneStatus()
      @unknown default:
          print("unknown")
      }

  }

  func checkMicrophoneStatus() {
      switch AVCaptureDevice.authorizationStatus(for: .audio){
      case .notDetermined:
          AVCaptureDevice.requestAccess(for: .audio) { granted in
              if granted {
                  print("Now it's granted")
              }
          }
      case .restricted:
          print("restricted")
          showConfigurationAlert(for: "microphone")
      case .denied:
          print("denied")
          showConfigurationAlert(for: "microphone")
      case .authorized:
          print(("authorized"))
          showNextVC()
      @unknown default:
          print("unknown")
      }
  }
  ```

What I did was, first check the camera authorization in checkAuthStatus and then, if the camera is authorized, trigger checkMicrophoneStatus() to check the mic authorization.
The reason why I think this code is unclear is, I only write a function to check the camera authorization in checkAuthStatus() funciton. I think if it is clear if I can write something like

```
func checkAuthStatus(){
    // check both cameara and microphone is authorized.
    // if both of them are authorized, show next VC with showNextVC() function.
}
```

Comment: If the camera authorisation status is not determined, you ask for permission, and then `checkCameraStatus` would return immediately, without doing anything about microphone, no matter what option the user chooses. Is this intended?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to add an `onAuthorised` closure parameter to both functions. The two `checkXXXStatus` functions also has quite a lot in common. We don't need to duplicate the switch statement.

```
func checkMediaStatus(type: AVMediaType, deviceName: String, onAuthorised: (() -> Void)?) {
    switch AVCaptureDevice.authorizationStatus(for: type){
    case .notDetermined:
        AVCaptureDevice.requestAccess(for: type) { granted in
            if granted {
                print("Now it's granted")
            }
        }
    case .restricted:
        print("restricted")
        showConfigurationAlert(for: deviceName)
    case .denied:
        print("denied")
        showConfigurationAlert(for: deviceName)
    case .authorized:
        print(("authorized"))
        onAuthorised?()
    @unknown default:
        print("unknown")
    }
}

func checkMicrophoneStatus(onAuthorised: (() -> Void)?) {
    checkMediaStatus(type: .audio, deviceName: "microphone", onAuthorised: onAuthorised)
}

func checkCameraStatus(onAuthorised: (() -> Void)?) {
    checkMediaStatus(type: .video, deviceName: "camera", onAuthorised: onAuthorised)
}
```

Then `checkAuthStatus` can be written as:

```
func checkAuthStatus(){
    checkCameraStatus {
        self.checkMicrophoneStatus {
            self.showNextVC()
        }
    }
}
```

Also note that you might also want to call `onAuthorised` and `showConfigurationAlert` in the `requestAccess` completion handler. I think this is a better design.

```
if granted {
    print("Now it's granted")
    onAuthorised?()
} else {
    showConfigurationAlert(for: deviceName)
}
```

Comment: thank you so much! I used your example and was able to write only one switch statement. Also. it was my first time using a function which takes a closure to its parameter. It was great to learn!

Answer (score 1):

You could change checkCameraStatus() and checkMicrophoneStatus() to return a bool and inside checkAuthStatus() change to :

```
func checkAuthStatus(){
    let cameraAuthorised = checkCameraStatus()
    let micAuthorised = checkMicrophoneStatus()

    if (cameraAuthorised && micAuthorised) {
        showNextVC()
    }
 }
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your quick response! I just used a different example, but I know this also works! Thank you for letting me know!

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for something like this:

```
let videoStatus = AVCaptureDevice.authorizationStatus(for: .video)
let audioStatus = AVCaptureDevice.authorizationStatus(for: .audio)

switch (videoStatus, audioStatus) {
case (.authorized, .authorized): showNextVC()
case (.authorized, _): showConfigurationAlert(for: "microphone")
case (_, .authorized): showConfigurationAlert(for: "camera")
default: print(videoStatus, audioStatus)
}
```

You can check both cases at the same time and handle each of them you like

Comment: Thank you so much for your response! I just learned that I can take two arguments for the switch statement! and this example is exactly what I wanted to do!